# Increase tags value maxLength of Elastic APM server

Tags: elasticsearch, open-telemetry, elastic-apm

I have set up an elastic search 8.x and I am sending data from a Java native open telemetry agent.

All the connection work **but**, when sending large data, elasticsearch truncated the tag's value to 1024 characters.
I do not have the problem when using jaeger or zipkin (but they are not compatible with an elastic 8.x backend yet).

The information about the limit is present in here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/current/data-model-spans.html#_example_span_document and another discussion is here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/character-limit-in-fields-longer-then-1024-truncated-with-ellipsis/280415/4

> It is not a problem of the number of fields, but maxLength of a field

Is there any way to increase this limit?

Comment: I'm afraid the limit is hard coded (https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-java/issues/449), and the subsequent github issues to make it configurable are still open (e.g., https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-java/issues/456)

Comment: What you present is the APM agent for Java. But I do not use the APM agent for Java but directly the otel agent ( that has no problem with value limit ). So I suppose the problem is in the APM server or in elastic itself? Maybe I can use another collector ( not zipkin nor Jaeger since they are not compatible with elastic 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally achieved to fix the 1024 issues.
To do so, I decided to **not** use the APM server but directly the open telemetry contrib collector / exporter for Elasticsearch

One can find it here (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/elasticsearchexporter)

The con is that it does not integrate well with the APM view of Kibana. But at least it is possible to store the document.